# My Jump not working so well C# Unity 2D Platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

Hi i was doing my player controller script after some hour of understanding how implement jump, i ended up with these:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveVelocity;
    private float jumpVelocity;

    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update() {
        bool jump = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);
        if (jump) {
            jumpVelocity = 5;
        }
        else
            jumpVelocity = 0;
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), jumpVelocity);
        moveVelocity = moveInput * speed;
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Do you have any tips for improving it?

Comment: What is your problem? Do you achieve to jump? If you dont, what is the outcome of your attempt?

Comment: At first you should provide information what is not working, what is it doing and how it is suppose to work. Secondly, this topic is really broad ("how should my jump work") and it can have many opinion-base answers. [We don't do that on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please try to use google and look through some tutorials like "How to make 2D jump - Unity C#". We would like to help you, but you have to clear this question with facts and non-ambigious question. Something like "do you have any tips" is really not valid question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AddForce instead of MovePosition with the ForceMode2D.Impulse property. It will be a nicer jumping mechanic.

Example:

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpVelocity), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```